# Got this as the error report when I was trying to launch Docker Quick Start Terminal on my Mac

Tags: docker, anaconda, macos-mojave

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 138, in main
    return activator_main()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 955, in main
    print(activator.execute(), end='')
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 180, in execute
    return getattr(self, self.command)()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 154, in activate
    builder_result = self.build_activate(self.env_name_or_prefix)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 285, in build_activate
    return self._build_activate_stack(env_name_or_prefix, False)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 307, in _build_activate_stack
    return self.build_reactivate()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 452, in build_reactivate
    new_path = self.pathsep_join(self._replace_prefix_in_path(conda_prefix, conda_prefix))
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 569, in _replace_prefix_in_path
    if path_list[last_idx + 1] == library_bin_dir:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

`$ /anaconda3/bin/conda shell.posix activate base`

```
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
        CONDA_BACKUP_HOST=x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
          CONDA_BUILD_SYSROOT=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk
        CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
                CONDA_EXE=/anaconda3/bin/conda
             CONDA_PREFIX=/anaconda3
    CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/anaconda3/bin/python
               CONDA_ROOT=/anaconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=1
         DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/Ronnit/.docker/machine/machines/default
                 NO_PROXY=<set>
                          PATH=/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/anaconda3
                          /bin
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>
```

```
 active environment : base
active env location : /anaconda3
        shell level : 1
   user config file : /Users/Ronnit/.condarc
```

```
          conda version : 4.6.14
    conda-build version : 3.17.8
         python version : 3.7.3.final.0
       base environment : /anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /anaconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/Ronnit/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /anaconda3/envs
                          /Users/Ronnit/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.6.14 requests/2.21.0 CPython/3.7.3 Darwin/18.5.0 OSX/10.14.4
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


    An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

    If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
    future releases of conda.
    Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?


    Timeout reached. No report sent.
```

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Comment: @DavidPostill do you mean that i should format the question or the body (the error report which i got while i was trying to run Docker Quick Start Terminal on my Mac)? Thanks.